# classList is not working in my web project

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
  menuToggle.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle.active {
  background-image: url(images/close.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- font awesome library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">


<!-- actual code -->
<div class="toggle" onclick="toggleMenu();"><i class="fas fa-bars" style="font-size: 50px;"></i></div>
```

I want to do if the function is worked then name of that class is 'toggle active' and then the toggle is work as per new class, css. But it is not working.

Comment: the code seems to be right. Are there more than one elements on your page having toggle class.?

Answer (score 0):

No problem with js. Check Your CSS

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
  menuToggle.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle{
  color: black;
}
.toggle.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- font awesome library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">


<!-- actual code -->
<div class="toggle" onclick="toggleMenu();"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-lg" style="font-size: 50px;"></i></div>
```